# Как скачать файл Excel созданный с помощью exceljs на компьютер, используя TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Всем привет. Я формирую workbook используя exceljs, но не понимаю с помощью чего я могу сохранить или скачать ее на компьютер. Подскажите, какие есть варианты?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
    let wb:Workbook = new Workbook();
      wb.title = 'Report - '+Date.now().toLocaleString();
      let sheet:Worksheet = wb.addWorksheet('Report');
      sheet.columns = [       
      { header: 'Name', key: 'Name' },
      { header: 'Age', key: 'Age'},
      { header: 'City', key: 'City'}]
      items.forEach((item:IExcelReportField)=>
      {  
        let rowValue = [];
        rowValue[1] = item.Name;
        rowValue[2] = item.Age;
        rowValue[3] = item.City;
       sheet.addRow(rowValue);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно создать xlsx-файл прямо в браузере:

- записываем данные в буфер командой `wb.xlsx.writeBuffer()`
- создаем из буфера `BLOB`-объект `new BLOB([bytes], ...)`
- создаем объектную ссылку командой `URL.createObjectURL(data)`
- выводим ссылку для скачивания файла (при желании можно сразу открыть закачку командой `window.open(url, '_blank')`, но данный метод менее гибок)

```js
import { useState, MouseEventHandler } from "react"
import { Workbook } from "exceljs"

function App() {
  const [objUrl, setObjUrl] = useState<string>()

  let test: MouseEventHandler = async (ev) => {
    const wb = new Workbook()
    wb.title = 'Report - ' + Date.now().toLocaleString()
    const sheet = wb.addWorksheet('Report')

    sheet.columns = [
      { header: 'Name', key: 'Name' },
      { header: 'Age', key: 'Age' },
      { header: 'City', key: 'City' }]

    items.forEach((item: IExcelReportField) => {
      let rowValue = []
      rowValue[1] = item.Name
      rowValue[2] = item.Age
      rowValue[3] = item.City
      sheet.addRow(rowValue)
    })

    const bytes = await wb.xlsx.writeBuffer()
    const data = new Blob([bytes],
      { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' })
    setObjUrl(URL.createObjectURL(data))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Create Report" onClick={test} />
      <br />
      {objUrl && <a href={objUrl} download="report.xlsx" >Download Report</a>}
    </div>
  )
}
```